# What are the steps for basic delegation implementation in objective-c for an iOS 7 app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, delegates

I have `PeopleTableViewController` and `ConfirmedTableViewController`

`PeopleTableViewController`: lists confirmed people for strictly viewing purposes only
`ConfirmedTableViewController`: same as above but with the ability to make pending or delete

My aim is to have changes made in `ConfirmedTableViewController` be reflected in `PeopleTableViewController` without needing to restart the app. I originally solved this by using a parse.com `[self loadObjects]` which reloads latest lastest changes made to objects back into an NSArray which is used in my tableView.

I placed this method in my `viewWillAppear` method in `PeopleTableViewController` and when clicking the `PeopleTableController` tab to bring me back to it's tableView it would be refreshed.

This was causing issues with another part of my app so had to remove it. I then hunted for some other solutions and came across `NSNotificationCenter`. This worked perfectly for me but I didn't like the idea of needing to remove the observer afterwards. Also it made sense to use delegation because `PeopleTableViewController` was the only class that needed to know about changes made in `ConfirmedTableViewController`.

**I simply added this to the block that is fired after my database was successfully updated:**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshTable" object:nil];
```

**Then in my viewWillAppear method in PeopleTableViewController I put:**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshTable) name:@"refreshTable" object:nil];
```

The above works fine but I'd like to use delegation.

**Here is my delegation implementation that isn't working:**

```
//MPConfirmedTableViewController.h

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "Person.h"
    #import <Parse/Parse.h>

    @class MPConfirmedPeopleTableViewDelegate;

    @protocol MPConfirmedPeopleTableViewDelegate <NSObject>

    - (void)confirmedOrDeletedPerson;

    @end

    @interface MPConfirmedPeopleTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController

    @property (nonatomic,weak) id <MPConfirmedPeopleTableViewDelegate> delegate;

    @end
```

**Here is where the triggering happens for taking a user offline:**

```
// MPConfirmedTableViewController.m
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [self showProgressHud];
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"People"];
        // Retrieve the object by id
        [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[[self selectedPerson] objectId] block:^(PFObject *person, NSError *error) {

            if (!error) {
                // will get sent to the cloud.
                person[@"active"] = @0;
                [[self searchDisplayController] setActive:NO];
                [person saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        [self loadObjects];
                        [[self delegate] performSelector:@selector(confirmedOrDeletedPerson)];
                     //   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshTable" object:nil];
                    } else {
                        [[self tableView] setSeparatorStyle: UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
                        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[self view] animated:YES];
                        [errorPopup show];

                    }
                }];

            } else {
                [[self tableView] setSeparatorStyle: UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[self view] animated:YES];
                [errorPopup show];
            }
        }];

    }
}
```

**The other controller that holds the method to be triggered:**

```
//MPPeopleTableViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Person.h"
#import "MPDisplayViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>


@interface MPPeopleTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController 
@end
```

**My implementation:**

```
// MPPeopleTableViewController

#import "MPPeopleTableViewController.h"
#import "MPContactFormViewController.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
#import "MPConfirmedPeopleTableViewController.h"

@interface MPPeopleTableViewController () <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate, MPConfirmedPeopleTableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation MPPeopleTableViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    MPConfirmedPeopleTableViewController *ctvc = [[MPConfirmedPeopleTableViewController alloc] init];
    [ctvc setDelegate: self];

}

- (void)confirmedOrDeletedPerson {
    NSLog(@"confirmed or deleted person");
    [self loadObjects];
}
```

**Here is what happens:**

I click a row in `ConfirmedTableViewController` and an actionsheet instance fires. One of the buttons on that instance is "take offline" and it set's a value in my database to 0 which means the object won't show up in the confirmed list anymore.

Well if the save was successful I want the confirmedOrDeletedPerson method fired so that if I return back to `PeopleTableViewController` by clicking its associated tab on the tabBar I see reflected changes in the `PeopleTableViewController`. However nothing is happening. Am I missing something? I have tried many different versions of implementing this using stackoverflow answers but none have work.

**Update**

TableViewController 6 needs to trigger a method in TableViewController 13.
So TableViewController 6 needs a reference to TableViewController 13.

I was creating a new instance (blindly following a tutorial).
This is so much more complicated than using notification center and I'm wondering if it's even worth the hassle for such a simple task.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using [[self delegate] performSelector:@selector(confirmedOrDeletedPerson)]; instead of simply [self.delegate confirmedOrDeletedPerson]; ? It makes sense to use performSelector if you are unsure at compile time whether the method exists or not, but you are not testing for the existence.

Comment: @MariusFalkenbergWaldal The tutorial I was following [here](http://enroyed.com/ios/delegation-pattern-in-objective-c-and-writing-custom-delegates) used it. What I'm trying to is just trigger the method in People from Confirmed after my db update in Confirmed.

Comment: Ok. You would usually use the performSelector if you are unsure if the object implements the given method. You would then first test for it (with respondsToSelector), and then use the performSelector inside the if statement. For your use, you could just call it directly, like in my previous comment. Can you just check if that makes any difference? What happens if you try to step into it with debugger?

Comment: Hmm, why are you creating an instance of ctvc in viewWillAppear? You need to set the delegate on it on creation, or you need to get the reference to the already existing object; not create a new ctvc intance.

Comment: I will give this a try. I was wondering how using a new instance of a controller rather than the one the one that needed to do the triggering would work and it confused me more. I'll give this a try and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `viewWillAppear` method in `MPPeopleTableViewController` is creating an instance of `MPConfirmedPeopleTableViewController` but not retaining it. The instance will be released after the `viewWillAppear` method. You need to define a property to hold the `MPConfirmedPeopleTableViewController` instance object. Also, there is no code to display the `MPConfirmedPeopleTableViewController` controller.

Here's an updated implementation that should work.

```
// MPPeopleTableViewController

#import "MPPeopleTableViewController.h"
#import "MPContactFormViewController.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

@interface MPPeopleTableViewController () <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPConfirmedPeopleTableViewController *ctvc;
@end

@implementation MPPeopleTableViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    self.ctvc = [[MPConfirmedPeopleTableViewController alloc] init];
    [self.ctvc setDelegate: self];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self presentViewController:self.ctvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)confirmedOrDeletedPerson {
    NSLog(@"confirmed or deleted person");
    [self loadObjects];
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the need for [self presentViewController:self.ctvc animated:YES completion:nil]; The tableView is already there. It's also giving me an error: reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: classname)'

Comment: Creating an instance of MPConfirmedPeopleTableViewController is not enough and you need to display the view controller. In case the MPConfirmedPeopleTableViewController is already being displayed, by say being a root view controller of a navigation controller, then you will have to create and manage an instance of MPPeopleTableViewController in MPConfirmedPeopleTableViewController and set the delegate there.

Comment: But my [self loadObject] method deals with all the refreshing of the UITable. I can call that any where in that class and it refreshes the tableView with latest data. All I would like to do is call it from ConfirmedTableViewController when I update my database.

Comment: @LondonGuy, creating the instance of  PConfirmedPeopleTableViewController with alloc init, is creating a different instance that the one you already have. You need to gert a reference to that instance, not create a new one. How you do that depends on your controller hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to just call the method from the save block like this:

```
[self.delegate confirmedOrDeletedPerson];
```

It is not necessary to declare the `MPConfirmedPeopleTableViewController` as a property in the  `MPPeopleTableViewController`. I use this pattern often, and usually does not create properties for view controllers like this.

Comment: This doesn't work either. When user is taken offline it doesn't trigger the method in the other controller to reload the table. I put a breakpoint on it and the method is ignored after the database update.

Comment: Ignored? Did you put a breakpoint in the method that does the calling? Or the called method?

Comment: Both, I think the reason it wasn't working was because I was using a new instance rather than referencing the one I was doing my saving in. I'm thinking of going back to using NSNotificationCenter, it seems like a lot of hassle right now. Plus I need the observer to listen for a notification from another controller when it makes a pending user live.